# Running Javascript on the Webview Child whose parent is also a Android Browsers webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am working on the Google's open source Android Browser, i am working for a requirement, where i need to show some content into a new webview like a popup dialog. I shall pass some HTML data to the Webiview. I am having some JS within HTML content but the JScript is running on the main page not on the custom webview i created. Please show some way out for it.

Answer (score 0):

Any JScript can be run on the webview, provided we have a script tag embedded in the HTML content rendered on custom webiew created.

Cheers